# Hay forma de implementar un repositorio ORM con un servicio Rest como datasource?

Tags: java, rest, orm

Quería hacer varias aplicaciones/modulos que se comuniquen mediante webservices Rest, me gusta usar el patron dao y estaba buscando si jpa o hibernete o spring data (en general un ORM), permitían hacer este tipo de cosas, es decir, consultar un repositorio jpa pero en ves de consultar una base de datos, consultara un webservice. Se que solo es crear las consultas al servicio en rest, pero quede con la duda profesional de si es posible usar un ORM o alguna otras implementacion que permita consultar un sobre un recurso rest.

Se me ocurrió de pronto exponer un servicio con ODATA, graphql y llamarlo como repositorio pero no encontré algo para leerlos desde un repositorio de un orm o algo parecido.

¿Hay forma de realizar esto de esa forma?,¿hay otra forma de implementar lo que quiero?,¿es un error querer hacer esto desde el punto de buenas practicas?, ¿se puede comunicar los módulos de otra manera?

Answer (score 1):

No se si comprendo bien la pregunta. Cualquier cosa me avisa.
Por empezar un framework ORM sirve para mapear entidades relacionales de una base de datos a objetos con los que puedas interactuar. Obviamente tienen mas cosas que gestionan la operatoria de la capa de persistencia de una aplicación.
Por otro lado la idea de un servicio REST es aprovechar el protocolo de HTTP para poder interactuar con por ejemplo una aplicación. Hay varias cosas en su pregunta, quizás lo que necesita es simplemente comunicar distintas apps mediante llamados http.

Para hacerlo puedes hacer que una aplicación responda ante distintas peticiones serializando algún objeto por ej en forma de JSON.
Otra aplicación que la consuma deberá efectuar el llamado a la primera y poder interpretar su mensaje.

Puedes usar muchísimas cosas para cada segmento de problema. Por ej, podría ser una aplicación con Spring que resuelva peticiones en forma JSON y otra que pueda consumirla (para hacer los llamados hay librerías, tanto nativas como no. Ej, las de apache o resttemplate) e interpretar directamente con spring a un objeto o usando GSON o JAXB. Las posibilidades son infinitas.

Hay varios tutoriales como https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/ o https://anotherdayanotherbug.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/implementar-un-cliente-rest-con-spring-resttemplate/

Hay otras formas de comunicación y quizás se aproximan a eso que necesita como las aplicaciones RMI donde puedes usar objetos que "viven" en otra aplicaciones, pero son soluciones un tanto en desuso y claramente no REST

Lo que si debe tener en cuenta es que cada solución está pensada para un problema específico. La conexión/comunicación, serialización, son independientes de problemas de persistencia.

En resumen cuando quiera por ejemplo guardar un objeto tendra que transferirlo a otra aplicación y en esa si lo desea guardarlo de la forma que mejor le resulte conveniente.

Comment: Si, lo que dices lo tuve en cuenta, el problema en especifico es que tengo una aplicación que esta separada en varios proyectos por que después van a agregarle muchas mas responsabilidades, la cosa es que tengo que comunicar dichos proyectos, todos tienen un api rest, mi duda es si no habia una forma consultar tipo base de datos a un servicio restfull, teniendo en cuenta la naturaleza de los servicios rest y que obviamente  tengo la estructura de las respuestas, pero veo que la comunicación que quiero hacer es demasiado idílica, en fin muchas gracias por la respuesta.